# In Ontario, does it matter which municipality issues the marriage license?

Tags: canada, marriage, ontario

The [Ontario government web page](https://www.ontario.ca/page/getting-married) tells you how to go to City Hall or a Municipal Office and get a marriage license. However, it doesn't say you can go to whatever municipality you feel like, nor does it tell you how to choose.

If a couple are both living in City A, and the ceremony will be in City B, must they get their license from A or B? Does it matter? If they both work in C and it's easier to stop by the C offices at lunchtime, is that OK? Or could there be a problem if the certificate was issued by the "wrong" municipality?

Comment: +1 and you might be interested in this new question I asked: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/61189/18614 because one municipality just told us that they won't issue us a marriage license because we don't live in that municipality and issuing a married license is not an "essential service" during COVID, but our municipality (Waterloo, Ontario) is not issuing marriage licenses at all right now, and the Ontario "shutdown" legislation lists "government offices" as being an essential service for the purpose of issuing "licenses and permits"!

Answer (score 3):

**Any municipality is fine**

In addition, they could get married in a different province and it would be a valid marriage in Ontario. They could also get married in a different country with which Canada has agreed to honour their marriages (i.e. most of them) unless they offend Canadian law (e.g. bigamy, child marriage etc.)

Comment: I am aware that marriages in one province are recognized in another. But I doubt they could show up in Manitoba with an Ontario marriage license and have the ceremony. That's my issue, where to get the license they will use in City B.

Comment: Dale are you able to give a reliable reference for your answer? There is no citation to anything here. Here: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/61189/18614, I have given two examples of articles that say that the municipality doesn't matter, but these are just articles. This article: https://owjn.org/2016/07/getting-married-in-ontario/ actually says the opposite, as it says  to get the marriage license from the city where you live.